# Передача строк в сокетах

Tags: c++

код сервера

```
    uint32_t sizeStr;
    string message;
    while (1)
    {
        if((sock = accept(socketR, NULL, NULL))>0)
        {
            bytes_read = recv(sock, &sizeStr, sizeof(uint32_t),0);
            bytes_read = recv(sock,&message, sizeStr,0);

        }
    }
```

код клиента

```
    string message = "hello";
    uint32_t sizeStr = message.length();
    send(sock,&sizeStr,sizeof(uint32_t),0);
    send(sock,&message,sizeStr,0);
```

Почему нельзя просто целиком отправить строку как в случае с uint32_t?Я знаю,что на стороне сервера нужен буфер,на клиентe привести к message.c_str(), но зачем?

Comment: Почему нельзя? Можно. Но если хотите получить на другой стороне текст, хранившийся в этой строке - то надо будет посылать этот текст а не байты объекта `std::string`. `recv(sock,&message, sizeStr,0);` приводит к неопределенному поведению так как класс `std::string` не является  trivially copyable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы как минимум не читали этот сайт - тут столько раз говорилось о том, как быть с такими не-POD объектами, что лично мне уже набило оскомину...

Вашим способом вы передаете не *содержимое* строк в вашем объекте, а их *служебные поля*. Строка содержит в себе указатель на выделенную где-то память, в которой содержатся интересующая вас информация. Но вы пытаетесь отправлять/получать просто эти указатели и другие служебные поля...

Получается примерно так - жена говорит собраться в отпуск и в машину в багажник сложить, ну, там, матрас надувной, палатку, мангал и шампуры - ну, в общем, барахло. Вы в багажник кладете бумажки с надписями "Матрас - на антресолях", "Палатка - на балконе" и т.д. Так вот передаете по сети (и, кстати, так же сохраняете в файл - это к тому, что точно по тем же причинам нельзя вот так же - через указатель - просто писать в файл)...

По приезду на место получаете/читаете (с сетью - даже не вы, а другой человек :), получивший вашу посылку) - вынимаете из бумажника бумажки с надписями, где что лежит. Но хуже того, что шкаф теперь совсем другой (если вообще есть - вы же на другом компьютере, в другой программе!), балкон тоже, так что втык от жены - это примерно и есть результат вот такого хранения и попытку раскрыть палатку, которой нет...

Что вам скажет жена/девушка, если вместо подарка вы ей вручите бумажку, на которой написано "красивое золотое кольцо"? :)

Именно поэтому передавать нужно не строку - объект `string`, а ее **содержимое** - те самые байты, указатель на которые получается с помощью `.c_str()`. И сначала длину - чтоб точно знать, сколько именно байт получать. А потом из этих данных восстанавливать нормальную строку-`string`...

Comment: `int a = 5;int *s = &a;send(sock, &s, sizeof(int),0);` @Harry Вы это имели ввиду?Именно такого типа данные отправлять недопустимо?

Comment: В частности. Здесь вы, кроме прочего, рискуете недопередать адрес- потому что `sizeof(int)` не обязательно равен `sizeof(int*)`. А так да - вы передаете адрес. А куда этот адрес будет указывать на компьютере-получателе?...

Comment: Как же я люблю перечитывать пример с женой)

Comment: @MrBin Да надо бы запомнить этот вопрос. Просто когда говорят о файлах - я помечаю как дубль. Но тут же **формально** - о сети, пометить как дубль не могу, приходится копипастить. Зато теперь если кто опять будет спрашивать с сетью - будет на что ссылаться как на дубль...

Comment: Я думаю стоит добавить ссылку на msdn и какую-нибудь линуксовую статью, где описываются функции `recv()` и `send()` для разных платформ. Вполне возможно, что аналогия с указателями не являются достаточным ответом для новичков.

Comment: Жуть. Остается лишь надеяться, что людям, которых так обучают в институтах, никогда не придется писать программы...

Comment: @avp Это вы о чем, о вопросе? ну так может еще просто не дошли до этих тем, а человек идет дальше и учится самостоятельно?...

Comment: @Harry, я о процессе обучения. Мало кто из преподаваемых (преподносимых в книгах о С++)  абстракций (чем выше уровень языка, тем больше абстракций) могут делать правильные выводы о сути явлений. Автор вопроса как раз это и демонстрирует.

Comment: @avp чем дальше изучаю с++,тем больше убеждаюсь, что мыслю неправильно.Возможно,стоит жалеть,что не выучился в институте.Не могли бы вы предложить что-то ,чтобы "абстракции" с++ закреплялись (книги, ссылки) как нужно?

Comment: @Dekopolskij, скорее всего не вы мыслите неправильно, а это С++ [неправильный язык](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/). Просто по возможности не используйте его, а о времени, потраченном на его не жалейте, запишите в накопленный опыт.